# How to draw table correctly on one page

Tags: longtable

I am trying to draw a table, but some of the fields are missing. The table fields are out of the page. 
I am using the following packages.

```
\documentclass{Dissertate}
\begin{document}

\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[c]{p{5cm}c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c }
    \hline
Parameter & Device & Table & Variable & night\_lowlimit & night\_upperlimit & day\_lowlimit & day\_upperlimit & sensor\_definition\\\hline 

Global\_radiations & DAR & EMB1.DAR & PYR.R.SWDR.Avg &0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & EB1.PYR.R.SWDR.001.AVG  \\   
Reflected\_irradiance & DAR & EMB1.DAR & PYR.R.SWUR.Avg & 0 &0&  0& 10 & EB1.PYR.R.SWUR.001.AVG  \\

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
 \end{document}
```

I am trying to draw table completely on one page. 
If someone help me to get rid of this problem. I will be grateful

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @ebo thanks for pointing out. I will edit it. I am new to this forum. .thanks

Comment: if you want the table on one page then do not use `longtable` the only thing that package does is allow tables to break onto multiple pages.

Comment: Your main issue here is that you have too much content to fit on one row. (It's like saying *"I would like the whole Lord of the Ring trilogy fit on the first line of my document"*.) What you could do is change the font size or allow breaks in your cell content (`p`-type column, or using `tabularx`/`tabulary` packages/environment). Yet at some point, you cannot make a very large content fit a limited space...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I try without longtable, but again the table fields are missing and they are cut out of the page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Above is the example data. you can try to draw that data table on a single page. But Thanks for guidance.

Comment: sorry I'd missed the edit although I do not have `Dissertate` class, I assume it will be Ok to use `article`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for help. I tried my best. but i am new to latex, so i am unable to solve this problem. .

Comment: Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- i haven't `Dissertate` document class, so i use `book` and width `geometry` package define margins to be 25mm
- i also assume, that the table can be fit in one page
- since table is doe to wide columns head wide than text width in `landscape` environment, i suggest to redesign column headers and use `\tnotes` from `threeparttable` for describing column titles meaning

```
\documentclass{book}%{Dissertate}
    \usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm} ccc *{4}{S[table-format=2.0,
                                    table-column-width=9mm]}c}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{night limit}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{day limit}                           \\
    \cmidrule(lr){5-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-8}
Parameter & Device & Table & Variable
    & {low\tnote{a}} & {upper\tnote{b}}
        & {low\tnote{c}} & {upper\tnote{d}} & sensor\_definition        \\
    \midrule

Global\_radiations & DAR & EMB1.DAR & PYR.R.SWDR.Avg &0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & EB1.PYR.R.SWDR.001.AVG  \\
Reflected\_irradiance & DAR & EMB1.DAR & PYR.R.SWUR.Avg & 0 &0&  0& 10 & EB1.PYR.R.SWUR.001.AVG  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]\footnotesize
    \item[a] night\_lowlimit
    \item[b] night\_upperlimit
    \item[c] day\_lowlimit
    \item[d] day\_upperlimit
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{landscape}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. both solutions works completely fine. I will accept your answer cox i am using this one. .but i am also thankful to bernard for his valuable time. .

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution turning the heads of the numeric columns 90° counterclockwise and using a `sidewaystable` enironment in the place of `landscape`. In adition, the rules from `booktabs` have some vertical  padding aroind them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
  \caption{A sideways table}\label{table:swtab}
  \begin{tabular}[c]{l*{8}{c}}
    \toprule
    Parameter & Device & Table & Variable & \rotatebox{90}{night\_lowlimit} & \rotatebox{90}{night\_upperlimit} & \rotatebox{90}{day\_lowlimit} & \rotatebox{90}{day\_upperlimit} & sensor\_definition \\
    \midrule
    Global\_radiations & DAR & EMB1.DAR & PYR.R.SWDR.Avg & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & EB1.PYR.R.SWDR.001.AVG \\
    Reflected\_irradiance & DAR & EMB1.DAR & PYR.R.SWUR.Avg & 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & EB1.PYR.R.SWUR.001.AVG \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. both solutions works fine for me. I will accept zarko answer as i am using that solution. But i am thankful to you for your precious time and help. .